# Data Dynamics : remove a control at run time

Tags: activereports

Hi I'm trying to remove an Image control at runtime...

```
var modifiedPic = (DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Picture)reportSection.Controls[controlIdx];
```

`modifiedpic.ResetImage()` only resets the image but doesn't remove the control.

I also tried  `modifiedPic.Image.RemovePropertyItem(771);`

This didn't work either. Is there any way to remove the control at runtime?

Also I want to set the `control.Location.X` value. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for assigning the loaction.X and location.Y points we have to define

```
System.Drawing.PointF x= new System.Drawing.PointF();
var modifiedPic = DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Picture)reportSection.Controls[controlIdx];//TargetControl:
var modifiedPic1 = (DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Picture)reportSection.Controls[controlIdx];//Control to get value of X:
x.X = modifiedPic1.Location.X;
modifiedPic.Location = x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This.
This Shoud remove the control.

```
var modifiedPic = (DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Picture)reportSection.Controls[controlIdx];
reportSection.Controls.Remove(modifiedPic);
```